# PhpStorm Tailwind Autocompletion not working inside of script tags

Tags: tailwind-css, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Autocomplete suggestions for Tailwind classes are working fine except if the string literal is surrounded by a `script` tag. File extension doesn't matter.

Works inside of js file:

[image]

Does not work:

[image]

Tried to reinstall PhpStorm, deactivate/activate Tailwind plugin - no change

PhpStorm version: 2023.3.2

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-65109 to be notified about updates.